# NullPointer exception when using second non-static reference to static object

Tags: java, multithreading, object, reference, static

I have a static object in a Class, where the Class is a writer, and then instances of that Class that need to refer to one of the static objects.  To avoid code duplication (where I'd have to write the same code multiple times, each where the only difference is in which of the static objects is used).
My solution was to have a static writer called writer1 and a static writer call writer7, and to then have a non-static writer called otherWriter, which in the constructor of either writer1 or writer7 points to the other writer.
However, I keep getting NullPointer exceptions when I access otherWriter.  Error and code below - any ideas?
Sorry, the code is not neat - it's hacky as only fiddeling about at this stage.
Thanks

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at popl.PoplFormative.generalWrite(PoplFormative.java:108)
    at popl.PoplFormative.run(PoplFormative.java:51)

package popl;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class PoplFormative extends Thread {

    int currentIndex = 0;
    int lastIndexWritten = -1;

    static int data[];
    int writerId;

    static PoplFormative writer1;
    static PoplFormative writer7;

    PoplFormative otherWriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        data = new int[10];
        writer1 = new PoplFormative(1);
        writer7 = new PoplFormative(7);
        writer1.start();
        writer7.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }

    public PoplFormative(int writer) {
        this.writerId = writer;
        if (writerId == 1) {
            this.otherWriter = PoplFormative.writer7;
        }
        else if (writerId == 7) {
            this.otherWriter = PoplFormative.writer1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Big nasty error occurred");
            while (true) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            generalWrite();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Exception Thrown");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void generalWrite() throws InterruptedException {
        while (currentIndex < 5) {
            //System.out.println(writerId + " writer has currentIndex; " + currentIndex);
            if (data[Math.max(lastIndexWritten,0)] == writerId || (lastIndexWritten == -1 && writerId == 7)) {
                write();
                synchronized (this) {
                    notify();
                }
                synchronized (otherWriter) {
                    otherWriter.wait();
                }
            }
            else {
                synchronized (otherWriter) {
                    otherWriter.wait();
                    write();
                }
                synchronized (this) {
                    notify();
                }
            }
            lastIndexWritten += 1;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(writerId + " has completed");
    }

    public void write() {
        System.out.println("writer: " + writerId + " currentIndex: " + currentIndex + " lastIndex: " + lastIndexWritten);
        data[currentIndex] = writerId;
    }

}
```

Comment: An object is not `static`. A reference is `static`. An object is not `null`. A reference is `null`.

Comment: sorry - lazy semantics. But you could also say that an Object is static when used in this way in a Class, as it's more than just the reference that's not changing, as it's in all instances of the Class?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The point here is that one of your variable has a `null` reference but you're trying to dereference it, causing  a NPE. Just find out which, probably `otherWriter`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is otherWriter that causes the NPE, but I don't understand why - otherWriter is assigned to point to either writer1 or writer7 in the constructor without fail, so no idea how it could then later cause a NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main`, you have

```
writer1 = new PoplFormative(1);
```

which invokes the constructor

```
public PoplFormative(int writer) {
    this.writerId = writer;
    if (writerId == 1) {
        this.otherWriter = PoplFormative.writer7;
    }
    else if (writerId == 7) {
        this.otherWriter = PoplFormative.writer1;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Big nasty error occurred");
        while (true) {
        }
    }
}
```

in which case, this code is executed

```
if (writerId == 1) {
    this.otherWriter = PoplFormative.writer7;
}
```

but `PoplFormative.writer7` is `null`, as it hasn't been initialized yet, so `otherWriter` also becomes `null`.

If you need these circular references, consider using setters.